# Login problems in android: fields are returning empty

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask

I am currently creating and android application for our thesis. I'm about finished with the app when I started having problems with the login. The fields are accepting the input when I try to toast it, but sends me a "Fields are empty" response when i send the data to the server. I got stuck working on this, so any help would be truly appreciated.

**This is my JSONParser class:**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method.equals("GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

**This is my login asynctask:**

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();   
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String emailaddress = EADD.getText().toString();
        String password = PASS.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mem_email", emailaddress));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mem_password", password));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://builtcycles.com/built_mobile/login.php", "POST", params);

        // check your log for json response
        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
        // json success tag
        try{
            success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {
                String memberId = json.getString("id");
                String memberName = json.getString("uid");

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                pDialog.dismiss();

                intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("id", memberId);
                intent.putExtra("uid", memberName);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                return json.getString("message");       
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString("message"));
                return json.getString("message");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is my login php:**

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        $email= $_POST['mem_email'];

        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblmembers where mem_email='$email'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $response["id"] = $row["mem_id"];
                $response["uid"] = $row["mem_fname"];

                if ($row["mem_active"]==1) {
                    if (md5($_POST['mem_password'])===$row['mem_password']) {

                        $response["success"] = 1;
                        $response["message"] = "Login successfully!";

                        echo json_encode($response);
                    } else {

                        $response["success"] = 0;
                        $response["message"] = "Invalid email or password";

                        echo json_encode($response);                             
                    }
                } else {
                    $response["success"] = 3;
                    $response["message"] = "Check your email for verification! Thanks.";

                    echo json_encode($response); 
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no products found
            $response["success"] = 4;
            $response["message"] = "No user found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }   
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 4;
        $response["message"] = "Fields are empty.";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

I have changed method == "POST"/"GET" into method.equals("POST"). Still, I am not able to send the data to the server. Is the problem coming from the jsonparser class, or in the doinbackground() of the asynctask?

Comment: Can you share the request string with us? So we can see the problem is in mobile app (Android) or server(php).

Comment: jean.osejo@gmail.com 
pass: Password.123

Comment: Don't use '==' to compare the value of two strings. Use equals()

Comment: @AndrewFielden you mean like this? method.equals("POST")

Comment: == compares the object addresses, not real string value, so use "abc".equals("abd") to compare only values

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot post your fields/request parameters to the server.

Comment: @ondermerol can u tell me where in the doinbackground() the problem is coming from?

Comment: Firstly update your Android code according to the @AndrewFielden comment and try it again to be sure that you POST your request not GET (Also update your question too).

Comment: Yes you need to establish which block of code is being triggered. Either put some Log statements in makeHttpRequest() method, or set a breakpoint. You should definitely be using equals() to compare String objects.

Answer (score 1):

Change the String comparison statements in

```
makeHttpRequest()
```

from

```
// check for request method
if(method == "POST"){
  ...
} else if (method == "GET") {
```

to

```
// check for request method
if(method.equals("POST")){
  ...
} else if (method.equals("GET")) {
```